# Why did the big bang explode if there is no oxygen in space?

Tags: cosmology, big-bang

If there is no oxygen in space, where the super dense singular object was suspended, then why did it explode because this reaction needs oxygen?

Comment: See [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point) for what the Big Bang was and therefore why oxygen wasn't needed.

Comment: Lucky there was no Chlorine Trifluoride around - that makes things explode even better than Oxygen. The universe might have been blown up even before it got started.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need oxygen to make an explosion.  All that is needed is that the reagents after the explosion occupy more space than those before.  Going from solid to gas is a good way of getting this effect.  Similarly, going from gas to solid is a good way of producing an implosion, but there is a limit on how much bang you can get from this.